# InnerException:When converting a string to DateTime. parse the string to date the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, type-conversion

I am trying to deserialize XML returned from an API call but am getting "InnerException:When converting a string to DateTime. parse the string to date the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object"

The XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<agentInventory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:N1="demo.org.uk/demo/CustomsStatus" xmlns:N2="demo.org.uk/demo/UnLocation" xmlns:N3="demo.org.uk/demo/AirCarrier" xmlns="demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventory">
  <shed>ADX</shed>
  <arrivalPort>
    <N2:iataPortCode>LHR</N2:iataPortCode>
      </arrivalPort>
  <masterAirwayBillPrefix>125</masterAirwayBillPrefix>
  <masterAirwayBillNumber>28121101</masterAirwayBillNumber>
  <nominatedAgent>DRB</nominatedAgent>
  <originPort>
   <N2:iataPortCode>BOS</N2:iataPortCode>
  </originPort>
  <destinationPort>
    <N2:iataPortCode>LHR</N2:iataPortCode>
  </destinationPort>
  <airCarrier>
    <N3:carrierCode>BA</N3:carrierCode>
  </airCarrier>
  <flightNumber>235</flightNumber>
  <flightDate>2012-02-09T00:00:00Z</flightDate>
  <npx>10</npx>
  <npr>0</npr>
 <grossWeight>123.0</grossWeight>
  <goodsDescription>BOOKS</goodsDescription>
  <sdc>T</sdc>
  <status1Set></status1Set>
  <status2Set>false</status2Set>
  <ccsCreationTime></ccsCreationTime>
  <customsSummaryText />
  <customsSummaryTime></customsSummaryTime>
  <agentReference />
  <isErtsPreArrival>false</isErtsPreArrival>
  <isAgentPreArrival>false</isAgentPreArrival>
  <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
  <finalised></finalised>
  <createdOn>2012-01-24T11:50:40.86Z</createdOn>
  <modifiedOn>2012-02-09T09:51:26.617Z</modifiedOn>
  </agentInventory>
```

The code used to deserialize the XML is

```
 if (storeXmlInventoryReturnData != null)
        {

            //DeSerialize XML from storeXmlInventoryReturnData variable
            agentInventory myInventoryResponse = null;

           XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(agentInventory));                             
          myInventoryResponse =  (
               agentInventory)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(storeXmlInventoryReturnData)

               );

            Console.WriteLine(
             @"\n\n\n INVENTORY RETURN DATA FOR AWB: {0}-{1} \n\n 
                          Destination Port: {2} \n 
                          Arrival Port: {3} \n 
                          Carrier: {4} \n 
                          Flight No: {5} \n 
                          Flight Date: {6} \n 
                          Customers Status: {7} \n 
                          NPX: {8} \n
                          NPR {9} \n
                          SDC Code: {10}                              
                          \n\n Hit any key to exit...."
                ,

                myInventoryResponse.masterAirwayBillPrefix,
               myInventoryResponse.masterAirwayBillNumber,
                myInventoryResponse.destinationPort,
                myInventoryResponse.arrivalPort,
                myInventoryResponse.airCarrier,
                myInventoryResponse.flightNumber,
               myInventoryResponse.flightDate,
               myInventoryResponse.customsStatus,
                myInventoryResponse.npx,
                myInventoryResponse.npr,
                myInventoryResponse.sdc,
               myInventoryResponse.grossWeight,
                myInventoryResponse.goodsDescription
                    );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("No data returned");
        }

    }
```

The exception is thrown at; 
    myInventoryResponse =  (
    agentInventory)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(storeXmlInventoryReturnData));

I guess I need to convert the myInventoryResponse.flightDate to a DateTime object but I am at a loss how to achieve this?

```
namespace FreightSolutions {
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/AgentInventory")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventory", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class agentInventory {

    private string shedField;

    private unLocation arrivalPortField;

    private string masterAirwayBillPrefixField;

    private string masterAirwayBillNumberField;

    private string houseAirwayBillNumberField;

    private string splitReferenceNumberField;

    private string nominatedAgentField;

    private unLocation originPortField;

    private unLocation destinationPortField;

    private airCarrier airCarrierField;

    private string flightNumberField;

    private System.DateTime flightDateField;

    private bool flightDateFieldSpecified;

    private string npxField;

    private string nprField;

    private float grossWeightField;

    private bool grossWeightFieldSpecified;

    private string goodsDescriptionField;

    private string sdcField;

    private System.DateTime status1SetField;

    private bool status1SetFieldSpecified;

    private bool status2SetField;

    private bool status2SetFieldSpecified;

    private System.DateTime ccsCreationTimeField;

    private bool ccsCreationTimeFieldSpecified;

    private customsStatus customsStatusField;

    private string customsSummaryTextField;

    private System.DateTime customsSummaryTimeField;

    private bool customsSummaryTimeFieldSpecified;

    private string agentReferenceField;

    private bool isErtsPreArrivalField;

    private bool isErtsPreArrivalFieldSpecified;

    private bool isAgentPreArrivalField;

    private bool isAgentPreArrivalFieldSpecified;

    private bool isDeletedField;

    private bool isDeletedFieldSpecified;

    private System.DateTime finalisedField;

    private bool finalisedFieldSpecified;

    private System.DateTime createdOnField;

    private System.DateTime modifiedOnField;

    private bool modifiedOnFieldSpecified;

    public agentInventory() {
        this.customsStatusField = new customsStatus();
        this.airCarrierField = new airCarrier();
        this.destinationPortField = new unLocation();
        this.originPortField = new unLocation();
        this.arrivalPortField = new unLocation();
    }

    public string shed {
        get {
            return this.shedField;
        }
        set {
            this.shedField = value;
        }
    }

    public unLocation arrivalPort {
        get {
            return this.arrivalPortField;
        }
        set {
            this.arrivalPortField = value;
        }
    }

    public string masterAirwayBillPrefix {
        get {
            return this.masterAirwayBillPrefixField;
        }
        set {
            this.masterAirwayBillPrefixField = value;
        }
    }

    public string masterAirwayBillNumber {
        get {
            return this.masterAirwayBillNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.masterAirwayBillNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    public string houseAirwayBillNumber {
        get {
            return this.houseAirwayBillNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.houseAirwayBillNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    public string splitReferenceNumber {
        get {
            return this.splitReferenceNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.splitReferenceNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    public string nominatedAgent {
        get {
            return this.nominatedAgentField;
        }
        set {
            this.nominatedAgentField = value;
        }
    }

    public unLocation originPort {
        get {
            return this.originPortField;
        }
        set {
            this.originPortField = value;
        }
    }

    public unLocation destinationPort {
        get {
            return this.destinationPortField;
        }
        set {
            this.destinationPortField = value;
        }
    }

    public airCarrier airCarrier {
        get {
            return this.airCarrierField;
        }
        set {
            this.airCarrierField = value;
        }
    }

    public string flightNumber {
        get {
            return this.flightNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.flightNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    public System.DateTime flightDate {
        get {
            return this.flightDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.flightDateField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool flightDateSpecified {
        get {
            return this.flightDateFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.flightDateFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string npx {
        get {
            return this.npxField;
        }
        set {
            this.npxField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string npr {
        get {
            return this.nprField;
        }
        set {
            this.nprField = value;
        }
    }

    public float grossWeight {
        get {
            return this.grossWeightField;
        }
        set {
            this.grossWeightField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool grossWeightSpecified {
        get {
            return this.grossWeightFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.grossWeightFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public string goodsDescription {
        get {
            return this.goodsDescriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.goodsDescriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    public string sdc {
        get {
            return this.sdcField;
        }
        set {
            this.sdcField = value;
        }
    }

    public System.DateTime status1Set {
        get {
            return this.status1SetField;
        }
        set {
            this.status1SetField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool status1SetSpecified {
        get {
            return this.status1SetFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.status1SetFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public bool status2Set {
        get {
            return this.status2SetField;
        }
        set {
            this.status2SetField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool status2SetSpecified {
        get {
            return this.status2SetFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.status2SetFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public System.DateTime ccsCreationTime {
        get {
            return this.ccsCreationTimeField;
        }
        set {
            this.ccsCreationTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ccsCreationTimeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.ccsCreationTimeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.ccsCreationTimeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public customsStatus customsStatus {
        get {
            return this.customsStatusField;
        }
        set {
            this.customsStatusField = value;
        }
    }

    public string customsSummaryText {
        get {
            return this.customsSummaryTextField;
        }
        set {
            this.customsSummaryTextField = value;
        }
    }

    public System.DateTime customsSummaryTime {
        get {
            return this.customsSummaryTimeField;
        }
        set {
            this.customsSummaryTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool customsSummaryTimeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.customsSummaryTimeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.customsSummaryTimeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public string agentReference {
        get {
            return this.agentReferenceField;
        }
        set {
            this.agentReferenceField = value;
        }
    }

    public bool isErtsPreArrival {
        get {
            return this.isErtsPreArrivalField;
        }
        set {
            this.isErtsPreArrivalField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool isErtsPreArrivalSpecified {
        get {
            return this.isErtsPreArrivalFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.isErtsPreArrivalFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public bool isAgentPreArrival {
        get {
            return this.isAgentPreArrivalField;
        }
        set {
            this.isAgentPreArrivalField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool isAgentPreArrivalSpecified {
        get {
            return this.isAgentPreArrivalFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.isAgentPreArrivalFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public bool isDeleted {
        get {
            return this.isDeletedField;
        }
        set {
            this.isDeletedField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool isDeletedSpecified {
        get {
            return this.isDeletedFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.isDeletedFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public System.DateTime finalised {
        get {
            return this.finalisedField;
        }
        set {
            this.finalisedField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool finalisedSpecified {
        get {
            return this.finalisedFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.finalisedFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    public System.DateTime createdOn {
        get {
            return this.createdOnField;
        }
        set {
            this.createdOnField = value;
        }
    }

    public System.DateTime modifiedOn {
        get {
            return this.modifiedOnField;
        }
        set {
            this.modifiedOnField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool modifiedOnSpecified {
        get {
            return this.modifiedOnFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.modifiedOnFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="demo.org.uk/demo/UnLocation")]
public partial class unLocation {

    private string itemField;

    private ItemChoiceType itemElementNameField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("iataPortCode", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("oceanPortCode", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public string Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="demo.org.uk/demo/UnLocation", IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType {

    /// <remarks/>
    iataPortCode,

    /// <remarks/>
    oceanPortCode,
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="demo.org.uk/demo/CustomsStatus")]
public partial class customsStatus {

    private string codeField;

    private string statusTextField;

    public string code {
        get {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set {
            this.codeField = value;
        }
    }

    public string statusText {
        get {
            return this.statusTextField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusTextField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="demo.org.uk/demo/AirCarrier")]
public partial class airCarrier {

    private string carrierCodeField;

    public string carrierCode {
        get {
            return this.carrierCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.carrierCodeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does `agentInventory` have custom serialization logic?  That's a pretty strange error message.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is because of `flightDate`'s value and not one of the other properties that have a reference to `DateTime` in their names, but have no values? (eg. `ccsCreationTime` or `customsSummaryTime`). Can you show the definition of `agentInventory`?

Comment: The blank values are expected as they may not always populated by the API.

Comment: I have added the agentInventory if that helps

Comment: With the code supplied, I am getting errors when it is trying to parse the fields I mentioned earlier, but with error `The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.` You will need to allow for those values to be null in your class, which is probably what the root cause of your error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my own sanity sake, I tried getting the provided XML to work with your classes and the nullable DateTime fields.

For them to work, replace the below properties with those linked below.
The default value for a `DateTime` object is `DateTime.MinDate`, so if the incoming value is null or empty, then the property will have a value of `DateTime.MinDate` anyway, for this you might need to additional validation/changes if your code needs to cater for this.

```cs
  #region XML Nullable helper properties
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "status1Set")]
  public object status1SetXml
  {
    get
    {
      // Return the main property itself here and not the field to ensure that if there are changes made to the getter,
      // the resulting XML will always have the right value
      return status1Set;
    }
    set
    {
      // value passed in is of type XmlNode[], so convert and get the XmlNode text, which should be the DateTime we want
      // !!ASSUMPTION!! That it will alwas be XmlNode[1] type
      XmlNode[] inputValue = value as XmlNode[];
      if (inputValue != null)
      {
        DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(inputValue[0].InnerText), out status1SetField);
      }
    }
  }

  [XmlElement(ElementName="ccsCreationTime")]
  public object ccsCreationTimeXml
  {
    get
    {
      // Return the main property itself here and not the field to ensure that if there are changes made to the getter,
      // the resulting XML will always have the right value
      return ccsCreationTime;
    }
    set
    {
      // value passed in is of type XmlNode[], so convert and get the XmlNode text, which should be the DateTime we want
      // !!ASSUMPTION!! That it will alwas be XmlNode[1] type
      XmlNode[] inputValue = value as XmlNode[];
      if (inputValue != null)
      {
        DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(inputValue[0].InnerText), out ccsCreationTimeField);
      }
    }
  }

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "customsSummaryTime")]
  public object customsSummaryTimeXml
  {
    get
    {
      // Return the main property itself here and not the field to ensure that if there are changes made to the getter,
      // the resulting XML will always have the right value
      return customsSummaryTime;
    }
    set
    {
      // value passed in is of type XmlNode[], so convert and get the XmlNode text, which should be the DateTime we want
      // !!ASSUMPTION!! That it will alwas be XmlNode[1] type
      XmlNode[] inputValue = value as XmlNode[];
      if (inputValue != null)
      {
        DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(inputValue[0].InnerText), out customsSummaryTimeField);
      }
    }
  }

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "finalised")]
  public object finalisedXml
  {
    get
    {
      // Return the main property itself here and not the field to ensure that if there are changes made to the getter,
      // the resulting XML will always have the right value
      return finalised;
    }
    set
    {
      // value passed in is of type XmlNode[], so convert and get the XmlNode text, which should be the DateTime we want
      // !!ASSUMPTION!! That it will alwas be XmlNode[1] type
      XmlNode[] inputValue = value as XmlNode[];
      if (inputValue != null)
      {
        DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(inputValue[0].InnerText), out finalisedField);
      }
    }
  }
  #endregion

  #region Non XML properties
  [XmlIgnore]
  public System.DateTime status1Set
  {
    get { return this.status1SetField; }
    set { this.status1SetField = value; }
  }

  [XmlIgnore]
  public System.DateTime ccsCreationTime
  {
    get { return this.ccsCreationTimeField; }
    set { this.ccsCreationTimeField = value; }
  }

  [XmlIgnore]
  public System.DateTime customsSummaryTime
  {
    get { return this.customsSummaryTimeField; }
    set { this.customsSummaryTimeField = value; }
  }

  [XmlIgnore]
  public System.DateTime finalised
  {
    get { return this.finalisedField; }
    set { this.finalisedField = value; }
  }
  #endregion
```